# If I buy the Destiny Legendary Edition, will my original game data be ignored/overwritten?

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I'm a year one Destiny player; I bought The Dark Below, House of Wolves, and I'm thinking about buying the Legendary Edition. My only concern is that I'm not sure if the data from my original Destiny game would be overwritten or ignored by the Legendary Edition. Would it create its own save files like a completely different game? I don't want to get Legendary if that's the case, because all of my items would be completely gone, along with god knows how much play time.

Comment: possible duplicate. other question is for a differant console, but they all work the same. Perhaps we should just get rid of the console tags and make it a universal question?

Answer (score 4):

No, your current characters will not be overwritten. Your characters are stored on Bungie's servers, not in the save file on your console (this is why you can go to [bungie.net](http://bungie.net), log in with your Microsoft/Playstation account, and see your characters).

Comment: As is the standard with all current AAA games from what I have seen.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, no. You will get a new copy of the game as well as all three expansions, but you will log in with your psn/xbon live account and it will transfer the data. If you have a destiny (bungie) account it is advisable to log into that as well. Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Destiny TTK, will install over destiny 1. All the items that you have obtained are saved onto Bungies servers, so you won't lose any progress at all. The only thing that destiny saves onto your console is the game and the DLC.

I hope this helped